# Attaching signal handler to multiple signals for Facebook like notification system in django

Tags: django, notifications, django-signals

I have implemented a notification system in my Django project, where a user gets notified whenever somebody comments their post/blog or likes it. I am basically making a database entry and fetch the unread notices each time to the user.

My table for the notification is

```
class notifications(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    object_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    object_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    n_reciever = models.IntegerField()
    n_sender = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.time = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(notifications, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Each time an object is commented or liked or set as favorite I can generate a signal, that will be caught by the signal handler responsible for making an entry in this table.

I am using a custom middle ware to check if there are new notices on each page refresh, by querying the table for objects whose `is_read` field is false. I have made the table generic so that it can contain notification for any type of activity.

So the situation boils down to this that I have multiple signals and for each signal I have the same signal handler that will make the required entry in the Database. How can I do this?

Can I do something like this

```
blog_liked.connect(notification_handler)
blog_set_favorite.connect(notification_handler)
.
.
.
```

i.e. relate same handler with multiple signals, I will ensure that all the signals send the same data.

I would also appreciate any feed backs on the technique I am using for generating notifications for the users.

Comment: It looks like you have it figured out? You can define new signals with `blog_liked = django.dispatch.Signal()`, if that was the question - if not, what specifically is the issue?

Comment: My question is that can I relate same handler with multiple signals

Comment: Yes, you can, you just connect each signal to the notification handler. The code you have looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream) which is a variant of what you're doing. The advantage of using it is that it's trying to match with the [Activty Streams](http://activitystrea.ms/) standards being developed.